# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 1.9.1@latest

Tags: npm, npm-install

I cloned a project to my local repo:

```
$  npm i 
npm WARN cropper@3.1.4 requires a peer of jquery@>= 1.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package iview is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package vuex is included as both a dev and production dependency.
```

But when I install the `jquery@>= 1.9.1` dependency manually , I get can not found error:

```
$ npm install jquery@>= 1.9.1 --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 1.9.1@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/luowensheng/.npm/_logs/2018-02-12T07_13_29_793Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this line

`npm WARN cropper@3.1.4 requires a peer of jquery@>= 1.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

means is you need to have a `jquery` version greater than 1.9.1

Just do

`npm install jquery@^1.9.1` or `npm install jquery@latest` if you want the latest `jquery` version which is 3.x.x